# Spring Batch Meta Data Schema Sequences

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, db2, spring-batch

This is more of a request for a quick explanation of the sequences used to generate ID from the Spring Batch tables that store Job and Step information.

I've ran the below sequences in DB2 for Spring Boot +  Batch application:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AR_REPORT_ETL_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ AS BIGINT MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NO CYCLE;
CREATE SEQUENCE AR_REPORT_ETL_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ AS BIGINT MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NO CYCLE;
CREATE SEQUENCE AR_REPORT_ETL_JOB_SEQ AS BIGINT MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NO CYCLE;
```

When the Spring Batch job is running, each ID field is being incremented by 20 on each new record. Though this isn't a major issue, it's still slightly confusing as to why.

I had removed the sequences and added them again with `INCREMENT BY 1`. This is now incremented every second record by 1 and the other record by 20.

Any tips or explanation would be a great learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons, Db2 for Linux Unix Windows by default will preallocate 20 numbers of a sequence and keep them in memory for faster access.

If you don't want that caching behaviour and can tolerate the overhead of allocating without caching, then you can use the NO CACHE option when defining the sequence.  But be aware that without caching, Db2 must do synchronous transaction-log-write for each number to be allocated from the sequence, which is usually undesirable in high frequency insert situations.

Remember to explicitly activate the database (i.e do not depend on auto-activation), as unused pre-allocated cached sequence numbers get discarded when the database deactivates.

Example no cache syntax:

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE AR_REPORT_ETL_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ 
AS BIGINT MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NO CACHE NO CYCLE;
```

You can read more details in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004201.html).